# Getting Youtube videos using json and php

Tags: php, json, youtube

I'm trying to get a video url and title from the Youtube API. Everything is working fine, but I can't show the data - I want to show url and title of the video using json and php only.

My code:

```
 <?php
$get = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=cod&orderby=viewCount&max-results=1&start-index=1&alt=json");
$decode = json_decode($get, TRUE); // TRUE for in array format

foreach($decode as $res) { 

echo $res['title']['$t'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You only asked your question three minutes ago - it can sometimes take half an hour, an hour, a day, or longer for somebody to answer your question. Please be patient.

Comment: ok, my question is how to get the data ? this query isnt working. i think im not using the correct tags ( $res['title']['$t'] ) ,im totally confused ! visit this url to figure it out : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=cod&orderby=viewCount&max-results=1&start-index=1&alt=json

Answer (score 6):

For this example, you don't really need the foreach loop because there's only one returned result, but for multiple results, you'll want to do something like the following...

```
foreach ($decode['feed']['entry'] as $entry) {
    echo '<a href="' . $entry['link'][0]['href'] . '">' . $entry['title']['$t'] . '</a><br />';
}
```